# What is the listen gem doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found the `gem listen` comes with a `rails new` as a gem in the development group.

I was wondering what it was doing and even reading the documentation (https://github.com/guard/listen) didn't help me any further.
It says it

> listens to file modifications and notifies you about the changes

I then also removed it from my app but didn't notice any changes. So my question is:

What is the `listen gem` doing? And in which cases is it helpful?

EDIT: I get, that these questions are too open to ask for stack overflow, but where can I ask questions like that than?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> listens to file modifications and notifies you about the changes

It watches your files as you change them. If you make a change and save it, `listen` picks it up and notifies whoever is subscribed.

This way, rails reloads your files when you save them. And something like `guard` can re-run affected specs.

Comment: Ok, I begin to understand. And as far as I understood `guard`, it then applies rules on what is happening when certain files or directories are actually changed.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why there's a gem for this feature. In my PC it depends on another very old gem: ruby_dep 1.5 which will cause an error saying it's not compatible with Ruby 3.0, however when I checked `listen` gem's dependencies, it does NOT depends on `ruby_dep`.

So I decide to not use it.

You can disable it by commenting this line out:

config/environments/development.rb

```
# config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

and everything goes well, your Rails still knows which files changed.

Comment: wouldn't it reload all the files if rails doesn't know which files changed?

Comment: please check the Rails source code and create an issue for this question. It's a so big question I really don't know how to answer .